# Disable dnsmasq on boot Raspbian Stretch

Tags: raspbian-stretch, dns, services

I need to disable `dnsmasq` from starting during boot.
So far I've tried

```
sudo systemctl disable dnsmasq.service
sudo update-rc.d -f dnsmasq remove
ENABLED=0 in /etc/default/dnsmasq
```

None of these work. During boot cycle it hits `Reached target Sound Card.` and after that it tries to start `dnsmasq.service`

`grep -nrI Default-Start /etc/init.d` contains:
`/etc/init.d/dnsmasq:6:# Default-Start:  2 3 4 5`

`systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled` dnsmasq not present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Raspbian` comes with `systemd`, the new init bootup system and replaces old style `SysV` init. For compatibility reasons and for old software not knowing about `systemd`, the `SysV` init is genereated by `systemd`. `man systemd-sysv-generator` says:

> systemd-sysv-generator is a generator that creates wrapper .service
>   units for SysV init[1] scripts in /etc/init.d/* at boot and when
>   configuration of the system manager is reloaded. This will allow
>   systemd(1) to support them similarly to native units.

What you have done was to mix up both systems so it is fairly possible that something is broken with your installation of `dnsmasq`.

For the future please only use `systemctl` and `journalctl` for managing services! There is no need to touch `/etc/init.d/`.

The simplest way to fix this is to flash the SD Card with a new image. If this isn't possible you can try to install `dnsmasq` again and purge it afterwards in the hope it will clean up your messed installation:

```
rpi3 ~$ sudo apt update
rpi3 ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi3 ~$ sudo apt install dnsmasq
rpi3 ~$ sudo apt --purge remove dnsmasq
rpi3 ~$ sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: I've figured it out yesterday night. It was rc.local starting dnsmasq after all. Network boot priorities changed from Jessie to Stretch and wpa_cli commands just return empty strings if service is not ready yet. Hence my command executing too early. I'll mark your answer as solution to close the question.